# any application to detect sound tone?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, audio

is out there any Android application that would tell me **what sound tone** makes my [Singing bowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singing_bowl)?

- HTC Desire on Android 2.1

Comment: Never heard of a Singing Bowl until now. Thanks Radek.

Comment: @gary comtois: never heard about them either. I knew the name Tibetian bowls :-)

Answer (score 3):

Any guitar tuning app should help.

(There should be some.. or else I'll make one.. ;)

Comment: I need the application to tell me. :-) I am not music literate at all :-)

Comment: Well, a well implemented guitar tuner tells you the tone you're closest to and how far from the perfect pitch it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Spectral Audio Analyzer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/spectral-audio-analyzer/radonsoft.net.spectralview)

Answer (score 1):

[gStrings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tuner-gstrings/org.cohortor.gstrings) is an awesome guitar tuning app.  It should do exactly what you want.  You can have it try to match a specific pitch or you can do "Tune auto" to find out what pitch you are currently at.

Comment: I guess I need the 'Tune auto' ... so far I am lost and cannot get what I want. Let me try